# Why is Gulp failing randomly with ENOENT error (or) failing to generate output (or accidentally deleted)?

Tags: node.js, gulp

## Software Environment

I am using **NodeJS v4.2.1** on Windows.
I have included my `gulpfile.js`, `bower.json`, and `package.json` files at the bottom.

---

## Additional Information

1. I don't have any IDE running at the moment. So it is definitely **not** a problem with files being locked by an external program.
2. I am running everything on the command prompt.

---

## Question

1. Is something wrong with my `gulpfile.js`?
2. Is this a bug with `NodeJS v4.2.1`?
3. Is this a bug with Gulp?

---

## Problem

I am experiencing these two problems when I run `gulp` at command prompt.

### Problem #1

My `build` folder would not be created every other time when I run `gulp`.
When I run it first time, it creates the `build` folder with `copy-bower` Gulp task output artifacts.

When I run it another time after it, `build` folder doesn't get created.
The gulp console output clearly shows my `copy-bower` task ran **after** the `clean` task, but I don't see the `build` folder created.

```
[21:21:32] Using gulpfile
[21:21:32] Starting 'clean'...
[21:21:32] Finished 'clean' after 3.66
[21:21:32] Starting 'copy-bower'...
[21:21:32] Finished 'copy-bower' after
[21:21:32] Starting 'default'...
[21:21:32] Finished 'default' after 6.

Directory: C:\Users\stun\Desktop\test-app

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       10/22/2015   9:00 PM                bower_components
d-----       10/22/2015   8:59 PM                node_modules
-a----       10/22/2015   9:30 PM            347 bower.json
-a----       10/22/2015   9:31 PM            421 gulpfile.js
-a----       10/22/2015   9:30 PM            301 package.json
```

---

### Problem #2

From time to time, I get either one of these errors.

```
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\stun\Desktop\test-app\build\bower_components\jquery\dist\jquery.min.map'
at Error (native)
```

Another Error

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\stun\Desktop\test-app\build\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\fonts'
    at Error (native)
```

---

## gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    del(['build']);
});

gulp.task('copy-bower', ['clean'], function () {
    var src = [
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**',
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/*'
    ];
    gulp.src(src, { base: '.' })
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['copy-bower'], function () { });
```

## bower.json

```js
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "description": "testing gulp and bower",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "authors": [""],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5"
  }
}
```

## package.json

```js
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing gulp and bower",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this in a repo somewhere that I can clone?

Comment: @James Louis's answer below is correct. I didn't `return` the `"clean"` task, and it was causing the other tasks to fail randomly due to file locks during writes and deletes. I don't have a repo for this as I am only playing with the Gulp and Bower. All the files I have are `gulpfile.js`, `package.json`, and `bower.json` from above.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your tasks do not return anything or call any callbacks, so Gulp thinks your tasks are done immediately. In particular, it won't wait for your `clean` task to have finished its work before starting to copy the bower files. The two may clash and result in filesystem errors.

Change your code to this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    // Return the promise that del produces.
    return del(['build']);
});

gulp.task('copy-bower', ['clean'], function () {
    var src = [
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**',
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/*'
    ];
    // Return your stream.
    return gulp.src(src, { base: '.' })
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['copy-bower'], function () { });
```

Comment: Thanks! I was turning crazy with this random file error :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was also the root cause of the issues I was having. I'll add that `run-sequence` might be helpful to synchronize gulp tasks when some tasks depend on the output of others! https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

Answer (score 10):

If the output shows that one task is starting before the previous is finished (especially "clean"), like this (see 'build' starting before 'clean' has ended):

```
[08:32:07] Using gulpfile ~/project/gulpfile.js
[08:32:07] Starting 'clean'...
[08:32:07] Starting 'build'...
[08:32:07] Finished 'clean' after 14 ms
[08:32:07] Finished 'build' after 15.53 ms
```

Use these techniques to fix it:

### Technique 1 - return a promise

As @Louis wrote, turn this:

```
del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    del(['build']);
});
```

into this:

```
del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del(['build']);  // see "return"
});
```

### Technique 2 - task's dependency

turn this:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  // some code...
});
```

to this:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function () {  // see 'clean' as dependency
  // some code...
});
```

### Technique 3 - tasks ordering

turn this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'serve', 'watch']);
```

into this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.start(['serve', 'watch']); // starts only after 'build'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly I find that this issue still occurs. The esiest solution (for me) is to use run-sequence:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('some-task', function() {
    runSequence(
        ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3'], // These 3 can be done in parallel
        'task-4', // ...then just do this
        ['task-5', 'task-5'], // ...then do these things in parallel
        'task-6', // ...then do this
        // ....
    );
});
```

found: https://davidwalsh.name/gulp-run-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone encounters this issue after following the solutions in this thread... I was executing my `clean` and `copy` task within a `gulp.parallel` instead of a `gulp.series` which was making my build task fail randomly. I spent 1 hour trying to figure out what the problem was but never noticing that small detail. Hopefully this is useful for someone